Prometheus Gauge Metric: Inconsistent Sum Over Time for Device Status
I have a gauge metric that tracks device_status (ON/OFF). I would like to determine how many seconds a device was ON for a given period (e.g., yesterday, the current week, or the current month).
For example, to calculate the ON time for the current week, I am using the following Prometheus query:
sum_over_time((device_status{device_id="101"})[604800s:1s] @1720368000)

Technically, the return value should be greater than or equal to the total seconds in the given period since it sums the value over time.
However, I am encountering inconsistencies in the results. Sometimes I receive a value of, for example, 6000 seconds, but other times it is 5200 seconds.
I don't understand why the value varies and doesn't always match the expected total seconds.
Could someone help me understand why this discrepancy occurs and how to ensure consistent results?
Edit
It only happens when I set the @ modifier with future.
My logic for a week is to select the time from the end of the week (e.g. Sunday 23:59:59) to one week equivalence seconds. Even though now is still Wednesday. In that case, this issue happens.
If I test for the previous week, that doesn't happen.

If I understand you correctly, and results vary between the runs for the same exact query, this sound more like a bug. Consider filing an issue in Prometheus' repo.

@markalex I am not very sure whether it's a bug. Yes, I run the exact same query and I am expecting the result should keep increasing. NOT decrease. The modifier is defined from the future. e.g. coming End of Sunday. If I set the modifier value to NOW, that doesn't happen.
